# What is the basic algorithm to convert a boolean circuit into a boolean formula and what is the complexity?

Tags: algorithm, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

As I am thinking, circuit and formula(expression) should be just two different representations of the same boolean and the big-O should just be n.  But someone said that they are not one-to-one corresponded, why?

Answer (score 3):

A boolean circuit is based on an arbitrary acyclic graph, while a boolean formula can be written as a tree. So a boolean circuit can evaluate a sub-circuit once and use the result of this in multiple places further on, whereas if you tried to write this out as a single formula in the obvious way you would have copies of the same sub-tree appearing in multiple places, which can blow up the size of the tree exponentially.

You can avoid this blow-up at the cost of increasing the number of variables by using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation

Comment: I just need to add: single formula implies only combinational logic circuit but if you got circuit representation you can not rule out sequential logic circuits (with memory or loops) which have arbitrary complexity and behavior.